# Find certain digits from column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want the extract the percentage from the following column in sql ex

```
123456789; 01/09/2014 00:00:00; 5%; 1896; 123456ae5.
```

I only want the percentage. it can change ie., it can have any percentage value. 
Just to clarify the percentage value will always be present after 2 semicolon

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: SQL Database, this is a value in a column. and i want to extract the percentage value

Comment: SQL is a language.  Databases have names like Oracle, or SQL Server, or BigQuery, or Postgres, or MySQL, and so on.

Comment: SQL Server @gordonlinoff

Comment: @GordonLinoff In my student years one friend asked me for help to write program. When I asked him on what languaged I should write a program, he answered me: "In English":)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server has lousy string manipulation functions.  Here is one method:

```
select v.*,
       right(v1.str, charindex(';', reverse(v1.str)) - 2)
from (values ('123456789; 01/09/2014 00:00:00; 5%; 1896; 123456ae5. ')) v(str) cross apply
     (values (left(v.str, charindex('%', str) - 1))) v1(str)
```

This looks for the `%` and gets rid of the string from that point forward.  Then it removes everything up to the character following the last semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Use string_split to convert fixed delimited string to row.Try below ,

```
select value from string_split('123456789; 01/09/2014 00:00:00; 5%; 1896; 123456ae5.',';')
```

where value like '%[%]%'

Output will be,

```
 5%
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty ugly, but it works ([Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8bcb1/22)):

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(
  value,
  CHARINDEX(';', value, CHARINDEX(';', value) + 1) + 1,
  CHARINDEX(';', value, CHARINDEX(';', value, CHARINDEX(';', value) + 1) + 1)
   - CHARINDEX(';', value, CHARINDEX(';', value) + 1) - 1
  )
 from data;
```

Basically finding the index of the second semicolon, and how many characters further the third semicolon is, and getting the substring of that.